# Javascript - Issue passing object from one JS file to another JS file

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, es6-modules, web-frontend, javascript-import

## Hello!

I am new to JavaScript. Please forgive my lack of JS vocabulary.

### Context

I have three files:

- index.html
- main.js
- sites.js

*index.html*

```html
<body>
  <h1>JavaScript Testing Zone</h1>
  <script src="/main.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

*main.js*

```javascript
import { sitesMod } from "/sites.js";
sitesMod();

console.log(sites);
```

*sites.js*

```javascript
function sitesMod() {
  var sites = [
    'https://site1.org/',
    'https://site2.org/',
    'site3.org/'
  ];
}
export { sitesMod };
```

### Explanation of code

**index.html** will run the **main.js** file.

**main.js** will import and run the function ***sitesMod()*** from **sites.js**

### Problem

`console.log(sites);` should output `https://site1.org/,https://site2.org/,https://site3.org/`

instead, `console.log(sites);` outputs `sites is not defined`

### What I know

I realize that I need to declare something like `var sites = X` in **main.js**, but I am unsure how to transfer the content of `var sites` on **sites.js** to `var sites` on **main.js**

So far using the import and export modules seem to be taking me in the right direction.I need to bridge the final step of transferring the variable's data from one file to another.

I hope I was able to describe my problem in an intelligible way. Please let me know if I can clarify the question. Thank you.

Comment: `function sitesMod()` doesn't `return` anything and running it does not create a global variable called `sites` - add `return sites` to the end of the functions, and do `var sites = sitesMod()` in main.js - I would recommend a refresher course on how functions work in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro, i've noted two mistakes on your code:

1. When you import and link your file on your `.js` and `.html` files you are pointing to the system root folder (eg. `type="/main.js"`, `import { sitesMod } from "/sites.js";` ). To point to the actual folder where are your folder use `./main.js` for example and not just `/`, or just remove it, are the same;
2. When you declare a variable inside a function it have a local scope and at the final of the execution is deleted, so you can not acess it outside of the scope, so:

```
import { sitesMod } from "/sites.js";
sitesMod();

console.log(sites);
```

Are wrong. Instead there are two ways:

1. At your `site.js`:

```
function sitesMod() {
  var sites = [
    'https://site1.org/',
    'https://site2.org/',
    'site3.org/'
  ];

  return sites;
}
```

At `main.js`:

```
import { sitesMod } from "./sites.js";

console.log(sitesMod());
```

2. Include a `console.log()` directly inside the function — the first is better ;):

```
function sitesMod() {
  var sites = [
    'https://site1.org/',
    'https://site2.org/',
    'site3.org/'
  ];

  console.log(sites);
}

export { sitesMod };
```

**Tip**: see more about scope and the difference between `var`, `let` and `const` and also more about Linux (you will understanding the `/` and `./`) and a such more.

I hope it helped you, good studies XD

*My english is a sucks, so forgive me for something...*

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here. `sitesMod` is function with no return value so when you call it in main.js nothing happens. Change the function to:

```
function sitesMod() {
  var sites = [
    'https://site1.org/',
    'https://site2.org/',
    'site3.org/'
  ];
  return sites;
}
```

Second issue is with the way you're using the function. Just calling the function doesn't declare a variable (`sites`) outside the body of the function. To access the `sites` variable you can do this:

```
import { sitesMod } from "/sites.js";

console.log(sitesMod());
```

I didn't try the code.

Answer (score 1):

`function sitesMod()` doesn't `return` anything and running it does not create a global variable called `sites`

One solution is

sites.js

```
function sitesMod() {
  var sites = [
    'https://site1.org/',
    'https://site2.org/',
    'site3.org/'
  ];
  return sites;
}
```

main.js

```
import { sitesMod } from "/sites.js";
const sites = sitesMod();

console.log(sites);
```

However, due to the trivial nature of sites.js - I'd be more inclined to simplify the code like

sites.js

```
const sites = [
  'https://site1.org/',
  'https://site2.org/',
  'site3.org/'
];

export { sites };
```

main.js

```
import { sites } from "/sites.js";
console.log(sites);
```